# Resolving Export / Imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a Namespacing.js with something like the following

```
(function(){

    window.GlobalObject = {
        foo : function() { console.log("bar"); }
    }

})();
```

Then i have another MyScript.js

```
GlobalObject.newAttribute = { ... }
```

So i'm now bundling with webpack and i was tryng to use modules on this, but i couldnt manage to do so.

At Namespacing.js i added at the end:

```
export default GlobalObject;
```

Then i tryed to import it in MyScript.js

```
import GlobalObject from "Namespacing"
```

But then my webpack gets me an error

```
[14:58:44] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (Kneat) (line: 1, col: 7, pos: 7)
```

Does any1 knows a good way of doing this export/import ?

Comment: If you put the `export` statement inside the IIFE it's illegal (you can only import/export at the top level, not inside a function or conditional). If you put it outside it has no access to `GlobalObject`. Remove the IIFE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch to `import`/`export`, you can't just add `exports` to your existing files, you need to change their structure (ever so slightly).

For instance, Namespacing.js would have either:

```
export const GlobalObject = {
    foo : function() { console.log("bar"); }
};
```

...to export a named symbol `GlobalObject`. That would be imported like this:

```
import { GlobalObject } from './Namespacing.js';
```

(You could use an `as` clause if you wanted a different name locally in the importing module.)

Or you could export that object as the *default* export:

```
export default {
    foo : function() { console.log("bar"); }
};
```

...and import it like this:

```
import GlobalObject from './Namespacing.js';
```

Note that in that case, you can use any name you want for `GlobalObject` in the module in which you're importing it (no need for as `as` clause).

---

Don't worry about the fact that it involves removing the IIFE; modules are inherently scoped, module code doesn't run at global scope.

Comment: I tryed that approach, so i`ve exported my module, it seems my problem is making GlobalObject actually global on WebPack -.-

Comment: You *could* do that by writing to `window`: `export const GlobalObject = { foo : function() { console.log("bar"); } }; window.GlobalObject = GlobalObject;` but at least one other module would need to import it to trigger that. And of course, globals are a bad idea in a module-enabled environment. (Life is messy, of course.)

Comment: I tryed this approach..


(function () {
   window.GlobalObject = GlobalObject ;
   alert("TRIGGER");
})();

Then on another js file that is being bundled with it:

`import GlobalObject from "GlobalObject"` having GlobalObject defined in Webpack ProvidePlugin and Alias. Still, GlobalObject is not defined. If i just wrap up the old way it was, its found... by all files inside the webpack bundle, if i change it to an export, it seems no file can find it.

Comment: @GabrielSlomka: Again, no need for the IIFE. Modules are effectively wrapped in one already. If the module is imported, its code is run (eventually), and `window.GlobalObject = GlobalObject;` will create a global (on browsers). Perhaps it's timing, you're trying to use it before the module code has been run. In any case, again, it really shouldn't be a global; that's why we have modules. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: NP, thanks for the info. I cannot make it not global as a huge code-base is based on this =( Ill look for another solution, maybe check the timings indeed. Thanks !